# Trying to figure our why Sendgrid's email API integration with Firebase Functions is returning "API key does not start with SG."

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, sendgrid, sendgrid-api-v3

I'm trying to integrate Sendgrid's Email API with my Firebase webapp. Here is what I've done:

1 - Installed Sendgrid's Mail package

```
npm install @sendgrid/mail
```

2 - Created an API Key on my Sendgrid Account

3 - Assigned the API Key to an environment variable using Firebase's environment configuration:

```
firebase functions:config:set sendgrid.key=SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

4 - checked to see if the environment variable was correctly assigned:

```
firebase functions:config:get
```

result:

[image: log of firebase environment variable]

5 - imported sendgrid mail and set API key:

```
import * as sgMail from '@sendgrid/mail';

const API_KEY = functions.config().sendgrid.key

const TEMPLATE_ID = functions.config().sendgrid.template
sgMail.setApiKey(API_KEY);
```

6 - created a new user trigger to send a test email

```
export const welcomeEmail = functions.auth.user().onCreate(user => {

    const msg = {
        to: user.email,
        from: 'contato@mycompanydomain.com.br',
        templateId: TEMPLATE_ID,
        dynamic_template_data: {
            subject: 'test subject!',
            name: user.displayName,
        },
    };

    return sgMail.send(msg);

})
```

7 - Deployed firebase functions:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

After doing this I'd expect that at least the API key would be set correctly, but I keep getting the following error from firebase functions log:

[image]

I can't figure out what is wrong. I've tried a few things:

1- creating a new api key and starting the process all over.

2- pasting the API directly into the sgMail.setApiKey() method. like:

```
sgMail.setApiKey("SG.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
```

All of which gave the same "API key does not start with SG" error.

Can you guys help me figure out what's wrong?

Versions

```
"@sendgrid/mail": "^7.2.1",
"firebase-admin": "^8.10.0",
"firebase-functions": "^3.8.0"
```

Thank you so much

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: any update on this?

Answer (score 0):

For does who had the same problem, I solved it by using the new firebase package and importing the config from firebase-functions.
So my code looks like this:

```
import functions, { config } from "firebase-functions";
import sendgrid from "@sendgrid/mail";
const MY_SENDGRID_API_KEY = config().sendgrid.key;
sendgrid.setApiKey(MY_SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```